# Website made on CSS Grid Layout, Prefixes issues on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, grid, css-grid, prefixes

I made [a website](http://lucasdebelder.be/stack/index.html), project using CSS Grid Layout. Everything looks nice on Chrome and Safari, but on Firefox it messes up, probably because of the prefixes.

For previous projects I used an tool that auto generates those prefixes, but with CSS Grid still being pretty new, those are outdated and does not support CSS Grid.

Any advice to make it work? I tried adding –webkit,-ms- and –moz- before the grid properties.Any good links for other tools that generate this prefixes?

[image]

Comment: probs -your website really looks awesome :D

Comment: You don't need prefixes for CSS Grid on Firefox. Get rid of all of them.

Comment: Also, your website looks exactly the same to me in Chrome and Firefox. Maybe you need to update your Firefox version.

Comment: But why does it look so weird on my Firefox browser than? I just edited my post with an image showing the problem i have on my browser.

Comment: What's version of FF?

Comment: version: 48.0.2 @Michael_B

Comment: Well that's the problem. FF began support for Grid with v52. See my answer in the duplicate for more details. Click on the caniuse.com link. Also, update your browser.